# Unable to load the new page source with beautiful soup4

Tags: python-3.x

```
open_submission = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='toogle-button fa fa-plus-square-o']")
open_submission.click()

response = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

the open_submission button clicks on a button to render a table. Then i want to store the updated page source in response object which i intent to pass to Beautiful soup but this code is grabbing the page source before the button is clicked(i mean the original page source with the button not being clicked). Isn't python synchronous? Or i am mistaken because i read somewhere that most python libraries are still synchronous? Or if the library is updated to be asynchronous then how do i maintain a callback funtion to trigger when the new page source loads?

Comment: For those who are caught in same trouble  use                                                     WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "table-questions"))
    ) where CLASS_NAME is the name of one of the classes you want to access due to trigerring

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait                                ,from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC as import statements